# Port mirroring, 1 source, two destination disadvantages

Tags: cisco, sniffing, port-mirroring

What are the disadvantages of having two port mirroring sessions?

I have a Cisco 2960 switch in which there is one session having Gi0/1 as source and Fa0/48 as destination.

- Is it possible to configure another session with the same port as source (Gi0/1) and another ethernet port (Fa0/1) as destination?
- If so, what are the disadvantages of doing so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Port mirroring will have impact on the performance, but as long as your equipment can handle the traffic and the drop in performance is acceptable for your traffic, you can keep it on long term.

Comment: That's my concern. The first session is used by MiaRec to record VoIP calls. I need to implement another solution (http://voipmonitor.org) and for testing purposes I need to have another session sending the traffic to another port where the new sniffer is connected to. All this without losing packages in the first session which is still in use.

Comment: So, is it possible to have the same port (Gi0/1) as source in two sessions?